# Django wagtail:- RichTextField vs Streamfields RichTextBlock styling first letter of paragraph.

Tags: css, django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

Now I am having a bit of an annoyance with the two. I need to specially style the **first letter** of the paragraphs. When using **RichTextField** the sample code in template works. To an extent it styles the first letter of the **RichTextField** but not the first letter of every paragraph with in it.

```
<span class="first-letter-styling">{{ page.translated_body | striptags | make_list | first }}</span>

{{ page.translated_body | slice:"4:" |  richtext }}
```

However when trying to do the same with a block in a stream field which is a **RichTextBlock** the above doesn't work. It simply out puts the entire block I don't even need to add the "| richtext " filter.

```
{% for block in blocks %}
    {% if block.block_type == 'block' %}
        {% with bs=block.value %}
            <h2>{{ bs.title }}</h2>
            <p>
                <span class="first-letter-styling">{{ bs.content | striptags | make_list | first }}</span>
            </p>
            <p>{{ bs.content | slice:"4:" |  richtext }}</p>
        {% endwith %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

So the intent of this code is to take the first letter style it then continue with the rest of the paragraph. This however does not work it takes the first letter styles it and then prints the entire paragraph including the first letter.

**So the questions are:**

How can i style each first letter of a paragraph for both **RichTextField** and **RichTextBlock** not just the first letter of the entire item.

How do i ensure it only applies to content within a paragraph. i.e if someone poputlated the content with just bullets (ul). The first letter styling will not apply. The best way for this to work would be if we could simply do all this styling from the wagtail admin panel for RichTextFiel and RichTextBlock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to wrap the first letter in a `<span>` to style it - CSS provides a `first-letter` pseudo-element for that. Combining that with the `<div class="rich-text">` which Wagtail automatically places around each rich text element, your CSS rule would be something like:

```
.rich-text > p:first-letter {
    color: red;
}
```